# Which one does Wordpress prioritize when it comes to php.ini, wp-config and .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, wp-config, php.ini

Let's say I want to change the max upload limit for a Wordpress website and I give the following values:

**wp-config.php: 128MB
php.ini: 256MB
.htaccess: 64MB**

So, which one would Wordpress prioritize while processing upon need?

Answer (score 14):

It's not clear from your question what you are changing in each of these files, but I presume in each case it is [the `upload_max_filesize` PHP setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads).

In general, settings will be applied in this order, each over-riding the previous value:

1. php.ini
2. Apache directives in .htaccess
3. calls to `ini_set()`

However, this setting is defined as `PHP_INI_PERDIR`, which [as explained on this page](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) means it cannot be set using `ini_set`, so the `wp-config.php` cannot change it. So in the example you give in the question, it will take the value from .htaccess of 64MB.

You can verify this by running `echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');` somewhere in your code.

Note that there are other places values can be set which I haven't listed above, such as per-user php.ini files, and [other Apache configuration contexts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context). Also, some of these [can be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841709/how-to-prevent-override-the-setting-using-htaccess-or-custom-php-ini), so if your server is not set to allow over-rides in .htaccess, you won't be able to set a value there either.

Also note that Wordpress includes some of its own configuration variables, which interact in different ways with the PHP configuration. For instance, `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` will attempt to *raise* the PHP `memory_limit` setting at startup, but has [code which checks and never lowers it](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/493f76a3d2ef8c030ab5dcd4333f9a401208f534/wp-includes/default-constants.php#L55). There's no general rule to this, it will be different for different settings.

Comment: php.ini is always the first to choose.

Answer (score 5):

Basically all three files are taken into consideration.

WordPress/your server will check in the following order:

`wp-config.php > .htaccess > php.ini`

If something on a "higher level" (later in the chain) is limiting your value, the former value will be ignored or overwritten. If a piece of the chain is missing, the value in `.htaccess` for example, the next higher one will be used instead.

In your example the `.htaccess` would limit the `max_upload_size` to 64 MB, although your server would be fine with up to 256 MB and WordPress would also accept up to 128 MB in file size first.

You can also [set a different limit via the `.htaccess` file](https://davidwalsh.name/php-values-htaccess) and by doing this you overwrite the value from `php.ini`, so that it is no longer the dominating value. This works in a lot of hosting environments, so chances are quite good you can raise *or* lower the `max_upload_size` in this way.

If you have a more strictly configured hosting/server, it is possible that [the option to override the settings from `php.ini` is disabled.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841709/how-to-prevent-override-the-setting-using-htaccess-or-custom-php-ini) In this case, overriding `max_upload_size` from `.htaccess` won´t work, so this could be a limiting factor.

Comment: How is this "not how it works" when you give a list of priorities, just as the question asks for? And if `.htaccess` is in the middle of the list, why would that one be the limiting factor?

Comment: I think my expression was unclear. I understood his question as "if I set a higher value in wp-config, will that 'dominate' the others?" and _that_ is not how it works. ;-) @bns did a better explanation on that.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean now. However, as I commented under bns's answer, I can find no documentation backing up the claim that you can't override with a higher value. The wp-config.php value will *always* be ignored, as explained in my answer, but I'm pretty sure a higher value in .htaccess would override a lower one in php.ini just fine.

Comment: You are partially right, but overriding php.ini values from .htaccess can be deactivated, see my updated answer.

Comment: Your update still implies you can only set a *lower* value via .htaccess. I know of no reason you couldn't also set a *higher* value there. The fact that the mechanism can be disabled is a good point, and one I glossed over in my answer, but assuming *any* PHP settings are allowed in .htaccess, then a value in .htaccess will absolutely "dominate" a value in php.ini for the same setting.

Comment: That is correct, will fix that in 30 seconds. ;-)

Comment: This answer still doesn't match with my understanding of how PHP options are processed; your description seems overly complicated, and in reverse order. I think it's really much simpler: for each setting there are built-in defaults; php.ini is read and over-writes these defaults; directives in .htaccess are executed (if allowed to do so by Apache's config) and over-write those values; `ini_set` in code could (if this setting was `PHP_INI_ALL` rather than `PHP_INI_PER_DIR`) then over-write those values. There's no process that hunts around for a value, just a variable, and ways of setting it.

Answer (score 3):

I think flomei should edit the answer, because that is the right answer but bad explaination.
`Php.ini -> .htaccess -> wp-config.php` is actually the order each file will be read and will set the values taking consideration that there is not setting previously defined.
But in the case there is a previously defined setting, this will be "over-ridden" only if the new setting is lower.

That means, if you have wp-config.php with 64Mb and .htaccess with 32 MB: wp-config.php won't override that setting because there is already a lower limit and you will end up with 32Mb.

But if you have wp-config.php with 32Mb and .htaccess with 64 MB, wp-config.php will lower the previous setting to 32Mb.

Edit: To clarify, as IMSoP points out, wp-config.php just lets you set a size that's more restrictive than what the PHP settings allow if you are changing 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', it doesn't let you go beyond that. So it's not actually a settings override. In fact, there are separated checks done at different points at runtime. If you are changing the php setting `upload_max_filesize` as he assumes (the question doesn't indicate which settings are you changing), that has no effect.

Also, you will have to take into account that the `post_max_size` must be greater than `upload_max_filesize` in your php settings

Comment: Can you link to any documentation for this "only over-riding if the new value is lower", because it's certainly not true of any other PHP setting I've seen. Nor is it mentioned [on this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads). What *is* mentioned, as I point out in my answer, is that `upload_max_filesize` cannot be changed at runtime (presumably because it's too late for it to have any effect) so `wp-config.php` can't affect it one way or the other. A built-in default of 2MB is also mentioned, and you can *definitely* set it higher than that.

Comment: That's basically what my hosting provider support team expained to me when I had the same issue, I will search for the e-mail and update if I find it.
I am not really sure if inside the server actually you override the value, or it's just that verifications are done in execution time at different places, thus the behavior is like this.

Comment: Just to reiterate, if the line you're adding to `wp-config.php` is `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '32M');` it will have *no effect, ever*, because that setting *cannot be set at run-time* as [it is defined as `PHP_INI_PERDIR`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads). (Unless that documentation page is wrong, but that seems unlikely.)

Comment: No, you are right. It's not really a settings override. Its just another separated restriction, i will update acordingly to avoid confusion.

Comment: @IMSoP / bns - I think there has perhaps been a bit of confusion between specific `wp-config.php` values and setting arbitrary PHP values with `ini_set()`. As I understand it, `wp-config.php` is primarily to do with setting WordPress specific config values and many of these are indeed _restricted_ (ie. imposed upper limit) by the underlying PHP config setting (such as `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` as mentioned in the answer). This is a WordPress thing. However, when setting arbitrary PHP config values using `ini_set()` in PHP there is no such restriction.

Comment: If you see, in my response I am talking about wp-config.php.
I am not talking about php.ini or .htaccess because that depends a lot of you server configuration:
- it is set to run as fastcgi? 
- does it have AllowOverride Options in Apache’s httpd.conf of nginx equivalent?
- did you restart the service?

So I am trying to clarify the behavior between the result of the php settings (this has nothing to do with wordpress, will be the same settings for joomla or whatever you are running) and your wordpress setttings

Comment: I did wonder if there was something other than the PHP setting being discussed, but since the question mentioned specifically the max upload limit, I could find no Wordpress-specific setting for that, and nobody has mentioned one, I'm not sure it's that relevant.  It looks like `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` does have some logic about min and max, and then sets the PHP `memory_limit` setting, [as shown here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/493f76a3d2ef8c030ab5dcd4333f9a401208f534/wp-includes/default-constants.php#L55); but it's hard to generalise about "WP settings will always work this way".

Comment: Also, unless I'm reading that code wrong, you have it the wrong way around - `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` will only ever *raise* the limit, never *lower* it. I don't know why, but that's what the code seems to be doing.